# WCF Client Proxy object Creation Issue

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using WCF service library where i return list. Then Create service reference in MVC-4 application. But Cant create proxy client object. Also i did configure service reference and set Collection type to System.Collections.Generic.List but still get problem.

Mu Code In Service Library is :

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IStudent
    {

       // [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Studentdata> GetData();


    }

    [DataContract()]
    public class Studentdata
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public string StudentId { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string Batch { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string Class { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string School { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string Domicile { get; set; }

    }

    StudentDataAccess obj = new StudentDataAccess();
    public List<Studentdata> GetData()
            {
                var query = obj.getalldata().ToList();
                List<Studentdata> obj1 = query.ToList().ConvertAll(new Converter<BtDataLayer.Student, Studentdata>(Converter.ConvertEntStudentToWcfStudent));

                return obj1;

            }
```

StudentDataAccess obj = new StudentDataAccess();
is entity project class object

Please help me out for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide any more information. Screenshots and code samples are always helpful. You've had several views, but I'm not sure what exactly you're doing. If you're simply trying to generate an endpoint then you should add a service reference to your project.

Comment: `WebInvoke`, it's look like REST service. It does not expose metadata, so you can't add reference to it